# Azure mobile services with Azure AD auth user Claims

Tags: cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

I wonder how I can get claims back when authenticating users with azure mobile services using Azure AD.

I'm using azure mobile services to authenticate users in a phonegap app. The authentication flow works fine, the response I get back from the service is as follows

```
{
    "userId": "Aad:o5ExTvSOMETHING_HEREpb0c",
    "mobileServiceAuthenticationToken": "A_TOKEN"
}
```

How can I get profile properties like full name, sign in name etc, so that I could at least output something like "Hello Lars", "Lars" being a claim returned.

After logging in, I redirect the user back to "home":

```
LoginController.prototype.doLogin = function() {
    var that = this;
    client.login('Aad').done(function(response) {
       that.ons.navigator.resetToPage("page1.html", { title: 'Home' });
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);            
    });
};
```

When HomeController runs after signing in, client.currentUser is an object with the structure above:

```
HomeController = function($scope) {
    $scope.controllerhello = "Welcome home!";
    if(client.currentUser == null) {
        $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage("login.html", { title: 'Sign in' });
    }
};
```

What I had hoped was a response like this:

```
{
    "userId": "Aad:o5ExTvSOMETHING_HEREpb0c",
    "mobileServiceAuthenticationToken": "A_TOKEN",
    "claims": {
        userName: "someusername@me.onmicrosoft.com",
        fullName: "Lars"
    }
}
```

How, if, can I get these claims. Does it have to do with the application manifest under manage azure AD -> applications -> manage manifest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Services does not send AAD claims to the client, but it is fairly easy to get them from the server using a custom API. Most of the data you will want can be obtained by making a call to the [AAD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx). This is where all of the information about your users is stored.

[This blog post](http://www.acupofcode.com/2014/01/accessing-aad-graph-information-from-azure-mobile-services/) shows the steps to access the graph and present an AAD user's name on screen using a Node.JS backend. It's a little outdated in terms of the UI, but the concepts should still apply. Now, instead of clicking "manage permissions," you will go to "permissions to other applications" and set the appropriate application permissions on "Windows Azure Active Directory."